# Display page in Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have this code (had to split t in 4 sections to display ok):

```
<div class="list_item" id="item_1">
<div class="list_item_int">Andrés Bedoya</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Soy Andr s Bedoya el programador de este maravilloso software">Soy Andr s Bedoya el programador de este maravilloso software</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Este es un trabajo de prueba para confirmar que todo funcione correctamente">Este es un trabajo de prueba para confirmar que todo...</div>
<div class="list_item_small"><a href="php/judge_detail.php?work_id=1">Archivos inscritos</a></div>
<div class="eval_buttons">
    <div class="approve" id="approve_1"></div>
    <div class="dismiss" id="dismiss_1"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="list_item" id="item_2">
<div class="list_item_int">Alexandra MÃƒÂ¡rquez</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Soy la esposa de Yo">Soy la esposa de Yo</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Prueba corta">Prueba corta</div>
<div class="list_item_small"><a href="php/judge_detail.php?work_id=2">Archivos inscritos</a></div>
<div class="eval_buttons">
    <div class="approve" id="approve_2"></div>
    <div class="dismiss" id="dismiss_2"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="list_item" id="item_5">
<div class="list_item_int">Pedro PÃ©rez</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Prueba o al menos eso creo personaje inventado">Prueba o al menos eso creo personaje inventado</div>
<div class="list_item_big" title="Este trabajo es el tercero de la categorÃ a Negocios tipo Individual que se escribe y espero que me solucione el problema de las lÃ neas hacia abajo y los botones que se borran">Este trabajo es el tercero de la categorÃ a Negocios tipo Individual...</div>
<div class="list_item_small"><a href="php/judge_detail.php?work_id=5">Archivos inscritos</a></div>
<div class="eval_buttons">
    <div class="approve" id="approve_5"></div>
    <div class="dismiss" id="dismiss_5"></div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

And this CSS to display it:

```
.list_item{ height: 48px; line-height: 24px; background: transparent url(images/bg_list_item.png) no-repeat scroll bottom; font-size: 0.7em; float: left; width: 100%; }
.list_item .list_item_int{ float: left; width: 230px; text-align: left; text-indent: 20px; font-size: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
.list_item .list_item_big{ float: left; width: 200px; text-align: justify; margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px; }
.list_item .list_item_small{ float: left; width: 130px; text-align: center; }
.list_item .eval_buttons{ width: 200px; height: 38px; float: left; line-height: 48px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; }
.list_item .eval_buttons .approve{ width: 93px; height: 25px; cursor: pointer; background: transparent url(images/boton_aprobar.png) no-repeat scroll top; float: left; }
.list_item .eval_buttons .dismiss{ width: 93px; height: 25px; cursor: pointer; background: transparent url(images/boton_descartar.png) no-repeat scroll top; float: right; }
.list_item a{ color: #195e87; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }
.list_item a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
```

But I keep getting a problem to display it correctly in IE8 while i have no problems with firefox or Google chrome (please take a look at the links to see it):

---

[See the problem](http://www.abedoya.com/problem_ie8.php)

is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Could you at least link to a page that actually has this problem? Putting this html in jsfiddle doesn't work because the images won't load.. kind of hard to bughunt without any working example.

Comment: Also, lists should be made of `<ul>`/`<ol>` elements with `<li>`'s in them, or in this case even a `table` since it looks alot like tabular data.

Comment: Whoa, now that's what they call "Divitis"

Comment: Instead of your humiliating answer, it would be nice to have an actual good answer to my problem. As I see, you are not even willing to try to make an effort. I know my code is not good, well right now I don't care if it's good or bad, i would only want to have a solution to my problem, which is not going to come from You, so please avoid posting any answers to my questions if they will not be constructive.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to replace all your  floats with  elements with fixed with (or percentage width).

Comment: The original css had not many floats, but it was not working neither in Firefox or Chrome, so i had to add this floats to all my divs to make it work for those 2 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

What happens id you give .dismiss a `float:left` too instead of `float:right`?

Comment: It's still the same, but both buttons will appear below their "supposed" position, aligned to the right. I have tried everything to keep them inside the class="eval_buttons" div, floated them to the left, to the right, reduced their size, but nothing seems to work. In firefox and Chrome on the other hand, it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Litso was kinda rude, offending my code, but it was ok. He made me realise that i could use another approach to the problem and solve it easily. I created a table and put all the information in trs and tds... this way, the last line never goes wrong and stays where it's supposed to be.
Well, thanks to Litso for that. I know my code is kinda poor, and i might suffer of "Divitis", but i'm just a junior programmer.

```
<tr class="list_item" id="item_1"> 
<td class="list_item_int">Andrés Bedoya</td> 
<td class="list_item_big" title="Soy Andr s Bedoya el programador de este maravilloso software">Soy Andr s Bedoya el programador de este maravilloso software</td> 
<td class="list_item_big" title="Este es un trabajo de prueba para confirmar que todo funcione correctamente">Este es un trabajo de prueba para confirmar que todo...</td> 
<td class="list_item_small"><a href="php/judge_detail.php?work_id=1">Archivos inscritos</a></td> 
<td class="eval_buttons"> 
    <a class="approve" id="approve_1"></a> 
    <a class="dismiss" id="dismiss_1"></a> 
</td>
</tr>
```